# HAML prevents template engines to render anything else than HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, haml, rabl, jbuilder

I am using Jbuilder (and I also tried to use Rabl) to render json.
When I try to render the jbuilder template in my application it renders
the template within the **layouts/application** file and returns **HTML** as JSON (see line 'within layouts/application'):

[Rides controller on Github](https://github.com/flov/Hitchlog/blob/jbuilder/app/controllers/rides_controller.rb)

```
Started GET "/random_photo.json"
Processing by RidesController#random_photo as JSON
>>  Rendered rides/random_photo.json.jbuilder within layouts/application (0.3ms)
    Rendered shared/_banners_in_corners.haml (3.0ms)
    Rendered shared/_sign_in_and_out.haml (2.0ms)
    Rendered layouts/_navigation.haml (7.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 120.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

However, when I render the json without a template, and do a `render json: @ride.as_json` call, things work as expected. 
When I create a new application and I try to do the same thing, everything works as expected as well:

```
Started GET "/posts/1.json"
Processing by PostsController#show as JSON
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered posts/show.json.jbuilder (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 19.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

I don't know what I have done with my application that it is not rendering the
templates correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Gosh, it took me about two days to find out that the issue that is causing this problem is
my layouts/application file which was named `aplication.haml`.

Now when I wanted to use a template engine like Builder for xml or Rabl for json, it tried to render the template within the yield field in the `layouts/application.haml` file and thus returning html as JSON

I found out that the problem lies within the `application.haml` file

naming it application.html.haml solved the problem...

Comment: Wow I was having the same problem! I was trying to implement Jbuilder with no luck, switched to RABL and was having the same program. Renaming application.haml to application.html.haml did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted.  This solved my problem and took hours to find this posting.

Comment: Upvoted.  This solved my problem and took hours to find this posting.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, we had the same problem. Took few hours to find your post.

Comment: Thanks, helped me out even 3 years later!