# Rails: JSON URL returning HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I have a Rails 4 application, and the URL localhost:3000/resources.json returns and HTML file, instead of JSON. The index.json.jbuilder is generated by Rails scaffold itself. Any idea why the JSON output is going wrong?

Comment: Can you post corresponding action and view

Comment: Finally, I got the answer. The issue is mentioned in another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425064/haml-prevents-template-engines-to-render-anything-else-than-html. I had the application layout named as application.haml. I renamed it to application.html.haml and it works now.

Comment: nice! Do you have a `respond_to` for json?

Comment: Yes. I have a respond_to block. I am changing all the files from .haml extension to .html.haml extension. Finding quite a lot of information now (after I asked the question). http://denysonique.blogspot.in/2012/03/rails-views-htmlhaml-vs-haml-htmlerb-vs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I will answer this question myself based on further searches.

- [HAML prevents template engines to render anything else than HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425064/haml-prevents-template-engines-to-render-anything-else-than-html)
- http://denysonique.blogspot.com/2012/03/rails-views-htmlhaml-vs-haml-htmlerb-vs.html